# Cylinder Misfire

Tags: misfire

I have a 2004 Grand Prix v6.  I got my coils checked and number 2 fire was real weak while the others are strong. Could that be why it's showing a misfire on cylinder one? I took it to AutoZone and they detected it.

Comment: Do I understand that it overheats while at idle but temp is normal while driving? How long does it take for the temp to return to normal?

Comment: I suggest asking two separate questions. Edit this question and remove either the overheating or misfire, and ask a new question for the other.

Comment: Yes mr.mike that is correct.an it didnt take no tim e to go back down maybe.a min or two

Comment: Ok mr.larry will do

Comment: Were there any codes? Is the CEL on? Did Auto Zone check the coils? If so how?

Comment: Not for sure about the codes he only said misfire in cylinder one.an he said  its spark  plugs an he said i jus need a tune up ..an yes CEL is on ..an no they didnt check the coils another guy did while i was watching one of the sparks were very strong while one of them was real weak(a lil spark)..

Comment: @mr.larry..how he checkd coils was by using a screw driver an touch metal or something...but when he did so...sparks came out

Comment: O Mr.larry sorrily to say i did get my spark plugs done like a week before i got o2  sensor no for sure if he gapped them right or at all.some one pl

Comment: Pulled one of the new plugs that were in an that was gapped all the way at or pass 70 when it supose to 60 an the guy took the new spark plug out and put a old one in checkn something..an was suppose to come back the next day but never seen again.. Smh so now i got 5 new an one old

Comment: An made a mistake at the begining..i meant one coil was very weak while the rest was strong..srry

Comment: Mr.larry the code was P0301

Comment: Help some one have to go to work in the am..

Comment: P0301/P0302/P0303/P0304 Always comes after a P0300(misfire detected) P0301 means it was on cylinder #1 (P0302 means #2, P0303 is #3 and P0304 means #4).

Answer (score 3):

In GM engines, a cylinder #2 misfires usually indicates a bad coilpack. Not *always*, but *usually*. To answer your question, yes, a poor spark will sometimes cause a misfire.

The correct way to check what's wrong is to swap two HT leads around (the cables coming from the coilpack and plugging onto the spark plugs).**CAUTION: swap them at both ends so that you don't make them fire out of sequence**. If the misfire stays on the same cylinder, it's not the lead, it's the spark plug or the coilpack, else it's the lead.

Next, swap two spark plugs around. If the misfire is on the same cylinder, and it's not the lead, then it's definitely the coilpack. Else it was the spark plug. Replace as necessary.

Also take note that a bad coilpack or HT lead will foul the spark plug in the misfiring cylinder. Best practice is to replace sparkplugs when doing the coilpack. It's also a good idea to replace the HT lead for that particular cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to know if the HT cables are in good condition (measure the resistant)
If not enough antifreeze used on cooling system rust will block thermostat (which will cause over heating)

Comment: Mr dick wat are ht cables? An when i took car to auto first time the said i needed a..o2 sensor ..a misfire in cylinder one an my themostate was below ..i got o2 sensor an.check engine light stil on ..so i took it back to auto zone then the only thing it detected was misfire oncylinder one .it no lon lone

Comment: It no longer detected that themostate was below..so wat u think

Comment: Did o2 sensor do the job for that

Answer (score 0):

this is old school but you never know.Could be a dud s/plug.Take out plug/refit lead/out
of gear/h-brake on.Use thick gloves and place plug end on block.Have someone turn engine over and check for spark May not be your problem but good to know.